# Expression in computed column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, calculated-columns

I have a table:

```
Col1
Col2
Total (computed column)
```

All are of **decimal(10,1)** type.

I want the value of Total to be the result of Col1 * Col2, but if the value of Col1 is less than 1.00, I just want it to be treated as 1.00.

Example:

```
Col1  Col2    Total
 -------------------
 4      2       8
 1      2       2 
 0.5    7000    7000 (here, total should not be 3500)
```

Comment: Decimal what? It helps to be precise. You should never declare a decimal without specifying precision / scale.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tablename ADD Total
  AS CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,1),
    (Col2 * CASE WHEN Col1 < 1 THEN 1.0 ELSE Col1 END));
```